# How to create 1G zeroed sparse file in windows?

Tags: windows, fsutil

In linux:

```
$ dd if=/dev/null of=mysparse seek=1G count=0
$ du -b mysparse
549755813888    mysparse
$ du -B1 mysparse
0       mysparse
```

In windows I have been playing with fsutil but I can not get the size on disk to be smaller than the size in the file properties.

Answer (score 22):

```
Type NUL > temp
FSUtil Sparse SetFlag temp
FSUtil Sparse SetRange temp 0 0x40000000
FSUtil File SetEOF temp 0x40000000
```

It Creates a New File, then Sets the Sparseness Flag for it, then Sets that specific Range to Sparse.
The size is in bytes.

You can also refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-sparse

Comment: Not very useful without an explanation of what each line does. So that I would know how to adapt it for my case.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Sorry, I thought it was fairly self-explanatory. It Creates a New File, then Sets the Sparseness Flag for it, then Sets that specific Range to Sparse. You can also refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-sparse

Comment: What's 0x100000 ? Size in kB? blocks? clusters? The OP asks for 1GB. `temp` looks like a name. And `fsutil` is probably case-insensitive. Finally, you first create the file and then mark a region in it sparse. So I have to first use up the full space, no way around it? The purpose of sparse files is specifically to not have to do that -- so that kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: The size is in bytes as the documentation says. I forget why I put a smaller amount but it was probably to mitigate someone pasting one line and then forgetting about a huge amount of space usage. As for allocating the full space, it doesn't defeat the purpose for most people since people usually just need speed & steady state space usage here, not a momentary spike in space allocation exceeding their free space. Btw I *believe* the commands they gave for Linux with dd do the same thing, though I'd have to check. If you want sparsity from birth, I'd have to find another way.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I updated the script to avoid the preallocation.

Answer (score 5):

May be this will help you: ["SparseChecker" - manages sparse files on Windows NTFS](http://web.archive.org/web/20160310151641/http://www.opalapps.com/sparse_checker/sparse_checker.html)
It allows to operate with files, not with individual blocks of files as "fsutil" does.

Comment: You must have [32-bit MSVC redist pkg](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999) installed for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

What @Mehrdad said is correct.

However, whatever you write to the file (even ranges of zero) would be considered data to the operating system (and thus space allocated) and only FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA() would allow non-space occupying zeros to be written.

`fsutil sparse setflag [file]`

would allow a file to be set as sparse file.